# Помогите разобрать код на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

вот код

```
my_string="python"
x=0
for i in my_string:
    x += 1
    print(my_string[0:x])
```

не могу понять что делает строка print где написано `print(my_string[0:x])`
что делает[0:x] как он достает элемент просто я такое видел когда к списку применяют
а не к строке

Comment: https://pythonz.net/references/named/slice/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это работает также как в списке. Так как строка это по сути почти тот же самый список из символов, и вы также можете обращаться к каждому символу по индексу.

```
my_string[0:x]
```

Значит берет строку с нулевого индекса до индекса с номером 'x'. Например:

```
my_string = 'Hello'
my_string[0:2]
```

Получаем:

```
He
```

Comment: спасибо. не знал что строки это тоже список из символов

Answer (score 2):

```
print(my_string[0:x])
```

так делаются срезы строки

```
text[pos_start:pos_end:step]
```

т.е. срез от начальной позиции до конечной с заданным шагом

в вашем случае сделается срез от начала строки (позиция 0) до x-ого символа строки (позиция x)

срезы можно делать как спискам, кортежам, так и строкам, на выходе будет или список (в случае для списка) или строка (в случае для строк)

вообще приведённый код несколько избыточен и можно было бы обойтись таким:

```
my_string="python"
for i in range(len(my_string)):
    print(my_string[0:i+1])
```

кроме того при срезах можно не указывать значения вообще, тогда они выбираются по умолчанию: 1 параметр считается равным 0, второй параметр считается равным длине списка/строки, 3 параметр считается равным 1

поэтому вместо `my_string[0:x]` можно было бы писать `my_string[:x]`

таким образом упрощенный код был бы таким:

```
my_string = "python"
for i in range(len(my_string)):
    print(my_string[:i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_string = "python"    # разберём данный алгоритм без цикла
x = 0                   # первый символ имеет индекс 0
x += 1                  # x = 1 
print( my_string[0:1] ) # выводим на экран букву p
x += 1                  # x = 2 
print( my_string[0:2] ) # выводим на экран две буквы py
x += 1                  # x = 3
print( my_string[0:3] ) # pyt
x += 1                  # x = 4
print( my_string[0:4] ) # pyth
x += 1                  # x = 5
print( my_string[0:5] ) # pytho
x += 1                  # x = 6
print( my_string[0:6] ) # python
```

Answer (score 0):

это обычный срез, вот его синтаксис [начало:конец:шаг]
допустим вот такая переменная со строкой есть `string = 'Hello World'` нам нужно только слово World и при помощи среза выполняем несложное действие `print(string[5:10])` и выведет только World